# how to create reCaptcha in zend2

Tags: html, zend-framework2

I have tried to create a reCAPTCHA in my zend application. I have tried the following, but gotten an error.

```
<?php
use ZendService\ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha;
$recaptcha = new ZendService\ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha("6LfjwfUSAAAAAB3-hAwIJsrr5pmzprOoIs0FvkDR" , "6LfjwfUSAAAAAGFmAXjPyKnETio8ktA-50UT8woK");
echo $recaptcha->getHTML();
?>
```

Comment: could you add more information about the error you have gotten.

Comment: I can not run the demo program, you can help me 1 instance. thank you